# Вывести дубликаты в порядке появления

Tags: python

Дана строка:

```
s = 'asdf qwer zxcv. zxcv fdsa rewq. qazw asdf sxed. qwer crfv asdf.'
```

нужно получить все слова повторяющиеся более одного раза, в порядке их появления:

```
'zxcv asdf qwer'
```

Первым делом я привожу все к одному регистру, удаляю все знаки пунктуации и делю строку по пробелам на список слов:

```
s1 = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s.lower()).split(' ')
```

После чего я получаю список дубликатов:

```
s2 = [(i, s1.count(i)) for i in set(s1)]
ans = [i[0] for i in s2 if i[1]>1]
```

Как мне отсортировать этот список в порядке появления, как еще я могу получить этот список?
Еслия пробую через разницу списков , в ответе повторяются слова, а должны попадать только один раз:

```
 s1 = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s.lower()).split(' ')

 s2 = list(set(s1))

 for i in s2:
     if i in s1:

 s1.remove(i)
```

Comment: Почему `'zxcv asdf qwer'`? Разве не такой должен быть результат `asdf qwer zxcv`? Ведь, например, `asdf` повторяется и он раньше `zxcv` в тексте

Comment: текст не един, а поделен на предложения. Нужно выводить слова из предложений. Т.е. в предложении: "asdf qwer zxcv" "zxcv" повторяется дальше в тексте, оно первое которое имеет дубликат. Его выводим, и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо большое, последнее решение вашего комментария подошло!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала можно посчитать частоту вхождения слов:

**Вариант 1** - воспользоваться [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

freq = Counter(s1)
```

**Вариант 2** - воспользоваться обычным словарем:

```
freq = {}
for word in s1:
    if word in freq:
        freq[word] += 1
    else:
        freq[word] = 1
```

**Вариант 3** - воспользоваться [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

freq = defaultdict(int)
for word in s1:
    freq[word] += 1
```

Чтобы получить список дубликатов из `freq`:

```
res = [w for w,n in freq.items() if n > 1]
```

Во всех случаях результат должен получиться одинаковым:

```
In [352]: res
Out[352]: ['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv']
```

---

Можно сделать все за один проход по списку `s1`:

```
freq = {}
res = []
for word in s1:
    if word in freq:
        freq[word] += 1
        if word not in res:
            res.append(word)
    else:
        freq[word] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием регулярки. Не очень красиво, но с вашим примером работает:

```
from re import search

s = 'asdf qwer zxcv. zxcv fdsa rewq. qazw asdf sxed. qwer crfv asdf.'
res, i = [], 0
while (m := search(r'\b\w+\b', s[i:])):
    if m[0] not in res and search(f'{m[0]}', s[:i]):
        res.append(m[0])
    i += m.end()
        
print(res)  # ['zxcv', 'asdf', 'qwer']
```